# Wait for part of child process to finish?

Tags: c, fork, wait

I have a fork occurring in a loop, and above the fork I prompt for a user's input. In my forked process, there's also some printing. Because there's no guarantee to the order the processes will run in, I often (or always) get lines from the child process printing between my prompt to the user and the place where they can enter information.

I.e., I get something like this:

```
Enter info: <OUTPUT FROM CHILD>
_
```

(where the _ indicates that the user is free to enter an input.)

Since I'm trying to allow my parent process to fork many children process (each based on piece of information given by the user) that run simultaneously, I can't wait for the child to end before letting the parent continue. Is there a way to make the parent wait for part of the child to complete before moving on?

Comment: have you considered using semaphores? if yes why did you decide against them and what else have you tried?

Comment: @UnholySheep I actually did. I tried setting a flag, and having the parent wait until it was set to 1 by the child (continuing if the flag was not 1), but on the second iteration the program stop responding. By printing flag, I saw that it wasn't changing (kept printing 0). So for some reason, it's trying to execute the parent, and won't do the 2 lines of the child I would like it to before going back to the parent.

Comment: If you still have that code you can try to open a new question about it, maybe we will be able to help you solve the problem there. I personally can't think of a better option that using semaphores for your kind of problem, but maybe somebody else will have a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on what you're really trying to do, but you can't use `waitpid()` or `wait()` to wait for part of a process to finish.  The wait family of functions wait on moribund processes, or processes that have been stopped due to a signal (SIGSTOP, SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, etc).

Some questions:

- Should the output from the child processes be sent to the screen, which leads to this confusion, or should it be sent to a file?
- Or, should the program have a pipe from each child so that it can read the output from the child and display it on an appropriate portion of the screen when it is convenient?
- Or, in a windowing environment, should the children's messages be sent to a different window (like the console window)?
- Or should the children write to the `syslog` daemon?
- Or should the children be made to hang on a SIGTTOU signal?

A lot depends on the purpose of the messages, and the importance of immediate display of the messages.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are definitely more general, and the proper way to solve this problem would involve some kind of pipe, but my case was actually very simple, and just needed the parent to wait for a while, so I added a `usleep()` line, to make the parent wait a few milliseconds for the child to finish printing. It's definitely not perfect, but it worked.